# Error: "The type cannot be used as type parameter in the generic type of method." Can this be solved with constraints or casting?

Tags: c#, generics, types

I ran into a compilation error while working on an experiment with factories. This is not an actual factory implementation I would use, as I would probably use a DI system in real code. I wanted to state this up front since that's not what I'm looking for help with.

What is confusing me with the snippet below is how to constrain the Create() method so that multiple types can be returned. The compiler error is:

```
The type 'TConcreteType' cannot be used as type parameter 'TConcreteType'
in the generic type or method 'Tests.IFactory<TFactoryType>.Create<TConcreteType>(int)'.
There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'TConcreteType' to 
'Tests.IFoo'.
```

Here is the important part of the sample code:

```
public static class UniversalFactory
{
    // New factories should be added here.
    private static readonly IFactory<IFoo> FooFactoryEx;
    private static readonly IFactory<IBar> BarFactoryEx;

    static UniversalFactory()
    {
        // These bindings could also be provided via a DI framework like Ninject.
        FooFactoryEx = new FooFactory();
        BarFactoryEx = new BarFactory();
    }

    // Maps concrete objects to factories according to the interface(s) they implement.
    public static TConcreteType Create<TConcreteType>(int id)
    {
        if (typeof(TConcreteType).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IFoo)))
            return FooFactoryEx.Create<TConcreteType>(id);
        if (typeof(TConcreteType).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IBar)))
            return BarFactoryEx.Create<TConcreteType>(id);
        return default(TConcreteType);
    }
}
```

The test code for the above looks like:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public void TestMain()
    {
        var foo1 = UniversalFactory.Create<FooImpl>(1);
        var foo2 = UniversalFactory.Create<FooImpl>(2);
        var bar1 = UniversalFactory.Create<BarImpl>(1);
    }
}
```

The error seems to be that TConcreteType has to be constrained to IFoo for this line:

```
return FooFactoryEx.Create<TConcreteType>(id);
```

While simultaneously (impossibly) constrained to IBar for this line:

```
return BarFactoryEx.Create<TConcreteType>(id);
```

However I would have expected the this to work without constraint since I am able to do type checking such as:

```
if (typeof(TConcreteType).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IFoo)))
```

However, no amount of constraint or type casting resolved the situation. Am I trying to do something impossible, or is there an obvious constraint implied from the compiler error that I have not tried yet?

**EDIT #1:** I should point out that "FooImpl : IFoo" and "BarImpl : IBar".

**EDIT #2:** This info was added for Chris Martin since I left out a crucial type constraint in my example:

```
public interface IFactory<in TFactoryType>
{
    TConcreteType Create<TConcreteType>(int id) where TConcreteType : TFactoryType;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have troubles understanding where this error is coming from you should try doing what compiler does - replace the generics with actual types. Here's what it will look like in case where `TConcreteType` is `FooImpl`:

```
public static FooImpl Create(int id)
{
    if (typeof(FooImpl).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IFoo)))
    //"where FooImpl : IFoo", returns FooImpl, looks fine
        return FooFactoryEx.Create<FooImpl>(id);
    if (typeof(FooImpl).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IBar)))
    //"where FooImpl : IBar". Wait... what?
        return BarFactoryEx.Create<FooImpl>(id);
    return default(FooImpl);
}
```

Doesn't make much sense, does it? Compiler has no way to know that `BarFactoryEx.Create<FooImpl>(id);` is never executed. There is no way to bypass that unless you are willing to remove type constrains from your `IFactory.Create<T>()` or dive into dynamic code generation :). In general i think your original approach was better (`UniversalFactory.FooFactory.Create()`)

Comment: Agreed. I ended up having this same conclusion come up in a conversation yesterday. The original approach is slightly less "clever" too, though the whole idea is probably too "clever" for actual use anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of the problem. This works just fine.

https://gist.github.com/trbngr/8911315

Comment: I added an edit for you in the OP, as there was a piece missing from your example that was in mine. Nikita Brizhak caught this too. I have an additional constraint for type safety that breaks my test. Whoops.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, typeof returns some different data type entirely that just tells what class something is. Two typeof's should have the same datatype, even if they're asking the typeof of two completely unrelated classes.

I think what you need to make this work is to have TConcreteType implement the IFoo and IBar interfaces.

Comment: If TConcreteType is constrained to both using 'where TConcrete Type : IFoo, IBar', then both lines continue to fail, since IFoo and IBar do not implement each other. The test is to see if you can pass in a concrete type such as FooImpl, and use a method to map that to a factory that handles whatever interface FooImpl implements, and use that factory for creation. Is what I tried to do impossible, and if so, in technical terms, why?